# How to add a document fragement to a div

Tags: javascript

I have this simple code. I need to add this ul html list to "my-div", but with this code I cannot add it. Any idea what is wrong?

Would be possible add the fragmentusing jquery?

```
 this.renderMenuTop = function() {

        var menu, f, ul;
        menu = ['menu-actuality', 'menu-archive', 'menu-pdf', 'menu-pictures'];
        f = document.createDocumentFragment();
        ul = document.createElement('ul');
        for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement('li')
            li.id = menu[i];
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }     
        document.getElementById("my-div").appendChild(f);

        //$(this.elmMenuTop).append(f);
    }
```

Comment: you are not adding the `ul` to the document fragment `f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never put anything in `f`. But why do you even have a document fragment?

```
this.renderMenuTop = function() {
    var menu = ['menu-actuality', 'menu-archive', 'menu-pdf', 'menu-pictures'];
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li')
        li.id = menu[i];
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    document.getElementById("my-div").appendChild(ul);

    //$(this.elmMenuTop).append(f);
};
```

If you need to append it to two different things, a document fragment won’t help.

Answer (score 2):

You never add any elements to your document fragment.  Add this after your `for` loop:

```
f.appendChild(ul);
```

Another option is to just dump the document fragment altogether and just:

```
document.getElementById("my-div").appendChild(ul);
//                                            ^^ Change from f to ul
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you add the list to the fragment?  You'd need to add

```
f.appendChild(ul);
```

before adding it to the div.  Alternatively, just add the list straight to the div without the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question, this is also possible with jQuery:

```
this.renderMenuTop = function() {
    var menu = ['menu-actuality', 'menu-archive', 'menu-pdf', 'menu-pictures'];
    var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
    for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        $ul.append('<li>' + menu[i] + '</li>');
    }
    $('#my-div').append($ul);
}
```